# font suitcase to ttf issue

Tags: iphone, ios, truetype, uifont

I used Mac OS Font Book to export fonts from it. I got 2 fonts files: Font Suitcase and PostScriptType.

Then I want to use these fonts in my iOS application, but to do that I need to convert them to, for example, ttf. But how?

May be someone faced this problem?

**Important:**
I don't need advices how to use custom fonts (such as ttf), I need advice how to use Font Suitcase and PostScriptType of fonts (may be how to convert it to ttf)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181007/iphone-custom-fonts-with-font-suitcase

Comment: I can't instal fondu on my mac. I think it is because the latest version of fondu is 2006 year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution doesn't require Fondu or Rosetta, but it does involve a little cut-and-paste into macOS's Terminal app.

Pretty simple, and free. And it works on macOS Mojave.

https://sittingduck.co.nz/2013/11/unpacking-the-suitcase/

Answer (score -1):

Try to use these steps.

```
1)    Add your custom font files into your project using Xcode as a resource
2)    Add a key to your Info.plist file called "Fonts provided by application".
3)    Make this key an array
4)    For each font you have, enter the full name of your font file (including the extension) as items to the UIAppFonts array
5)    Save Info.plist
6)    Now in your application you can simply call [UIFont fontWithName:@"CustomFontName" size:12] to get the custom font to use with your UILabels etc…
```

Also: Make sure the fonts are in your Copy Bundle Resources.

Comment: I can't use this method, because Font Suitcase even doesn't have extencion. I it can't be used like ttf file. So I need to convert it to ttf first

Comment: without .ttf file you cant use this format.First download .ttf file.

Comment: I need to convert Font Book file to ttf