# ios label with attributed text fonts not displaying correctly

Tags: ios, fonts

labels in xcode aren't correctly displaying some fonts even though attributed text is selected...

In storyboards I have some labels that I changed the text from "plain" to "attributed" but the fonts I wont to use wont display correctly - instead xcode, or whatever is controlling it, displays what seems to be a fall-back font.

Any workaround?
Reasons why?

I'm trying to use `schoolhouse cursive b` (and yes it does show up in the list of fonts)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iOS Devices don't have the font `schoolhouse cursive b` preinstalled:
[Font list iOS7](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5878)
[Font list iOS6](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5484)

If you want to add a custom font, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2616101/2115477).

Comment: haven't tried yet...but `schoolhouse cursive b` is a .suit file - will that work?! (gonna try it out now anyway...just curious)

Comment: [This Website](http://marcboquet.com/blog/2011/10/29/font-suitcase-fonts-in-ios/) tells how to convert it. And [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5228122/2115477) could be helpful as well.